# Python Regex: Separating 'kg' and 'g' or 'ML and 'L'

Tags: python, regex

Task is to separate the attributes of a product from its string. I am using regex to separate the required parts but having difficulty in distinguishing "L" from "ML" (or "l" from "ml"). Similar case for "kg" and "g" as regex always chooses the shorter string.

```
prod = 'TestProduct- 200 ML x24'
searchobj =  re.findall('([0-9]+).*(g|kg|ltr|l|ml)\s*x*[*]*([0-9]+)', prod, re.I)
print(searchobj)

#output
[('200', 'L', '24')]
```

How to make output as following?

```
[('200', 'ML', '24')]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make the `.*` non greedy `.*?`

Comment: Replace `.*` with `\s*` - https://regex101.com/r/8UQqqv/1

Comment: Both of your solutions are robust to having a variation of no-space in strings. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

You could specify that you only want whole words of the form `(g|kg|ltr|l|ml)\s` by changing that to `\s(g|kg|ltr|l|ml)\s` (require a space before and after the expression).

Comment: It works but doesn't \s match a whitespace char? What if the string was 'TestProduct- 200MLx24'? (No whitespace)

Comment: @MashhoodAhmad this is why it is important to give a few test-cases with example input and expected output in the question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(g|kg|ltr|l|ml)\s*x*\**(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OxBq5V/2).

**Details**

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a dot and then one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(g|kg|ltr|l|ml)` - Group 2: one of the char (sequences)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `x*` - 0 or more `x` chars
- `\**` - 0 or more `*` chars
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 3: one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a dot and then one or more digits